# Redirection with Apache2 query_string with square brackets

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, query-string, httpd.conf, querystringparameter

I have a URL like

```
http://domain.net/documents?f[author]=43
```

Which should be redirected to

```
http://domain.net/documents/author/43
```

What I have so far is

```
RewriteEngine On    
Rewritebase /documents
RewriteCond %{query_string} f([^/]+)=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) author/%2? [R=301,L]
```

However, this redirects all URLs, including 
    http://domain.net/documents/author/43?page=1 
back to 
    http://domain.net/documents/author/43 
when I just need to replace the "?f[author]=" part with "/author/"

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419645/how-can-i-use-htaccess-rewrite-to-remove-square-brackets-from-a-query-string

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On    
Rewritebase /documents

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{query_string} f([^/]+)=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) author/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, it seems my stuff is somewhat more complicated than I thought earlier, it looks like I just need to redirect when the full phrase "?f[author]=" is in the URL what do I put instead of

RewriteCond %{query_string} f([^/]+)=(.*)$ [NC]

If I want pages where a string "?f[author]=" appears?

Comment: Many thanks Gerben, this works in the first instance when "?f[author]=" is redirected, but on the subsequent URL (click more), I get documents/author/23054?page=1 where it should be documents?page=1&f[author]=23054 - I am guessing another expression is required where to redirect URL from documents/authors/FIRST?page=SECOND to documents?page=SECOND&f[author]=FIRST 

Can you help?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Could add your entire htaccess.

Comment: I have this so far:
    
    DocumentRoot /home/website/prod
    
    RewriteEngine On 
    
    <Location "/documents">
    RewriteEngine On 
    
    Rewritebase /documents
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
    
    RewriteCond %{query_string} f(\[.+\])=(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) author/%2? [R=301,L]
    </Location>
    
It redirects, as expected,
    http://domain.net/documents?f[author]=43 to 
    http://domain.net/documents/author/43

Now, I need to redirect 
    http://domain.net/documents/author/43?page=1 to 
    http://domain.net/documents?page=1&f[author]=43

Comment: But how does `domain.net/documents/author/43` get processed? Is there actually a file, called `43` in `/documents/author`?

Comment: It is a MySQL Query using Drupal Views, Author 43 does exist in the system

Comment: It comes from a Drupal module, however, with mod_rewrite, I just need to redirect the two patterns, the first one (documents?f[author]=nn to documents/author/nn) is fine, however, I need to get back from documents/author/nn?page=xx to doculments?page=xx&f[author]=nn as well

Comment: This does not look like a good solution. In the QueryCond you are using `f([^/]+)=(.*)$`, so the entire rest of the query string is in the %2. Why not use something like `...=([^&]*)(&|$)`. Maybe I overlooked something but explaining the answer might be helpful. Also, it might be better to check for "author" as well - maybe explain how brackets are handled in regex / query string and if they can't.