# How can I use htaccess rewrite to remove square brackets from a query string?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Just can't get this to work.

Trying to get this:

```
www.myexample.com/querypage.php?query=[blabla]
```

to redirect to this:

```
www.myexample.com/querypage.php?query=blabla
```

I can get it to work when it's not in a query string like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\[(.*)\] /$1$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But the query string eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(query)=\[(blabla)\]$
RewriteRule ^(querypage\.php)$ /$1?%1=%2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.